# How to suppress expected reply when using <int-jms:inbound-gateway>?

Tags: spring-integration, spring-jms

I am using  to listener to jms queue messages, everytime i run my app i see below mentioned log which says it was expecting a reply but did not receive any.

```
2014-07-10 11:22:28,280 DEBUG [org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer#0-3] jms.ChannelPublishingJmsMessageListener - expected a reply but none was received
```

Is there any way i can supress this, may be by using channel adapter instead of gateway will supress it BUT i want to know if using gateway i can supress it or not ?

Comment: It's a DEBUG message, which you normally wouldn't see in production. Why do you need to suppress it?

Comment: But i dont want it to expect a reply at all.

Answer (score 0):

Since we see the `DefaultMessageListenerContainer` looks like you are using `<int-jms:inbound-gateway>`.

And if you really don't prepare something as reply you should use one-way listening component - `<int-jms:message-driven-channel-adapter>`

Comment: I know using using <int-jms:message-driven-channel-adapter> wont show this log BUT what i am asking is using inbound jms gateway is there any way i can make this gateway not to expect any reply. I know gateways are bi-directional and have request/response mechanism but i just want to know.